# In gradle is it possible to include a different jar based on a flag

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

If I have a simple gradle java build, can I somehow swap out one of the jar dependencies, say **jarX** for **jarY** based on a flag?

e.g.:

if running `./gradlew build` - then include **jarX**

but if running `./gradlew build -specialBuild` - then include **jarY** instead of **jarX**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use conditional statements on the `dependencies {}` closure.

```
dependencies {
    if (project.hasProperty("useX")) {
        implementation 'x:x:x'
    } else {
        implementation 'y:y:y'
    }
}
```

call as

```
gradle -PuseX=true
```